# Sort a linked list in C++

Tags: c++, list, sorting, linked-list, queue

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to write an algorithm to sort a linked list, but I'm having a hard time coming up with something that will work. What we need to do have a linked list that contains a name in a string, and an `int` for hours. After displaying the list and the sum of the hours, we then have to sort the list in ascending order by the hours in a queue. I have the list and all it's functioned stored in a class object, as you will see. I cleared the whole function of what I had in hopes of coming up with a fresh idea but nothing is coming to mind. I initially was going to create a second linked list that had the sorted list, but then I began to wonder if it was possible to sort it within the same list. Here is my code as of posting.

```
#include   <iostream>
#include   <ctime>
using namespace std;

// OrderedLL class
template<class T>
class   OrderedLL
{
private: 
struct NODE
{
    string  sName;
    int sHours;
    NODE    *next;
};
NODE    *list;
NODE    *rear;

public:
// Constructor
OrderedLL () { list = rear =  NULL;}

// Insert item x -------------------------------------
void    Insert(string x, int y)
{
    NODE *r;
    // Create a new node
    r = new(NODE); r->sName = x; r->sHours = y;
    r->next = NULL;
    // Inserts the item into the list
    r->next = list;
    list = r;
}

// Display the linked list --------------------------
void display()
{ NODE *p = list;
while( p != NULL)
    { cout << p->sName << "/" << p->sHours << "-->"; p = p->next;}
cout << "NULL\n";
}

// Delete x from the linked list --------------------
void DeleteNode(T x)
{
NODE *p = list, *r = list;
while( p->info != x) {r=p; p=p->next; }
if( p == list)
    { // delete the first node
    list = p->next; delete(p);
    }
    else
    { r->next = p->next; delete(p);}
}

// Sort by hours ------------------------------------
void    sortHours()
{
NODE    *p, *q;



}

// Display the total hours --------------------------
friend  T   totHours(OrderedLL  LL)
{
    NODE    *p;
    int total = 0;  

    p = LL.list;
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        total += p->sHours;
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout << "Total spending time = " << total << endl;
}





}; // end of OrderedLL class

int main(void)
{
    // Declare variables
time_t          a;
OrderedLL<int>      unsortedLL;
OrderedLL<int>      sortedLL;
int         inHours;
string          inName;




// Displays the current time and date
time(&a);
cout << "Today is " << ctime(&a) << endl;

// Asks the user to enter a name and hours 5 times, inserting each entry
// into the queue
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter name and Time: ";
    cin >> inName >> inHours;
    unsortedLL.Insert(inName, inHours);
}

// Displays the unsorted list
cout << "\nWaiting List-->";
unsortedLL.display();
totHours(unsortedLL);

// Calls for the function to sort the list into a queue by hours
unsortedLL.sortHours();

unsortedLL.display();
return 0;

} // End of "main"
```

As always thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort

Comment: [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort)?

Comment: Try it with 5 scraps of paper with sample data written on them. Walk through the code whilst rearranging the paper.

Comment: Understand that doing anything that rearranges nodes in a linked list is going to be shot full of errors the first five times you attempt it.  Be *very* careful.  Do walk-throughs like Peter suggests above.  Plan the code so that you can easily debug it (eg, break long expressions into short components so you can log intermediate results).

Comment: The formatting on your code leaves much to be desired.

Answer (score 1):

Try sorting the linked-list like you are sorting an integer array. Instead of swapping the nodes, swap the *contents* inside the nodes.

Comment: I actually like the swapping idea. It's just figuring out how to make it work for the entire list that is bugging me still, but I feel like that gives me a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about efficiency you can use any sorting algorithm. What's different between linked lists and arrays is that the *swap* operation, to swap the position of two elements while sorting, will be a lot slower because it has to run through the links of the list.

An O(n²) [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubblesort) is easy to implement with a linked list since it only swaps an element with its neighbor.

If you care about efficiency you can look into implementing the [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergesort) algorithm even if it's a little more complicated.

Comment: i think he's not bothered about it..he just wants to get it running and 2 knw how..

Comment: It took me years to realize that merge sort is ideal for a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert like this

```
void Insert(string x, int y)
{
    NODE *r;NODE *temp;
    // Create a new node
    r = new NODE; r->sName = x; r->sHours = y;r->next = NULL;
    if(list==null)//check if list is empty
    {
    list=r;//insert the node r in the list
    }
    else
    {
    temp=list;
    while(temp->next!=null)temp=temp->next;//reach to the end of the list
    temp->next=r;//insert it at the end of the list
    }
}
```

No need of **rear pointer**..just check if `list->next` is `null`,if yes you are at the end

and your `sorthour` function should be

```
void sortHours()
{

    for(NODE* n=list;n->next!=null;n=n->next)//get each of the node in list 1 by 1 except the last one i.e. n
    {

        for(NODE* n1=n->next;n1!=null;n1=n1->next)//compare the list n node with all the nodes that follow it i.e.n1
        {

            if(n->sHours > n1->sHours)//if one of the node is the less than n
            {
                //swap n and n1
                node temp=*n;
                n->age=n1->age;
                n->name=n1->name;
                n1->age=temp.age;
                n1->name=temp.name;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. The program got hung up and crashed when it got to the sort hours function, and when displaying the list it only displayed the last two items.

Comment: @user1675108 is it inserting properly with above function..is it the problem with sortHours function only

Comment: @user1675108 i was using the same list for iterating..corrected it

Comment: The formatting of the code in your answer makes it quite difficult to read.